# unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Probably it is just a silly mistake but i am having a Instantiate activity message when i tried to run my second activity

My first activity :

```
package com.burak.algonder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "opucuk!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();   
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pozsyon.class));

        } 
    });

    }

}
```

My second Activity:

```
package com.burak.algonder;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Pozsyon extends Service  implements LocationListener {


    private double[] getGPS() {
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
      Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

     Location l = null;

     for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
      l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
      if (l != null) break;
     }

     double[] gps = new double[2];
     if (l != null) {
      gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
      gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
     }

     return gps;
      }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.burak.algonder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.burak.algonder.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.burak.algonder.Pozsyon" >

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Pozsyon" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                </intent-filter>
  </activity>



   <receiver android:name="com.burak.algonder.SmsReceiver" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

        </intent-filter>

        </receiver> 


           </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `Pozsyon extends Service` and not `Activity`. A service cannot be started as an activity.

Comment: You should always post the logcat output when you are asking about an application crash.

Comment: **Off-topic:** the "stack-snippet" is for runnable code in a browser. The code blocks ({}) or ctrl+k should be used for posting code. [See the meta post here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pozsyon Class is not Activity and can't be started here!